# Do I Need to Submit Facebook app for review if my app uses Facebook analytics tool?

Tags: ios, facebook, api, object, facebook-apps

In my app I am using Facebook analytics 
(e.g: **[FBSDKAppEvents logEvent:FBSDKAppEventName{XXXX}]**;) to track various app events from my app.

For recent changes in facebook app review process its mentioned that App needs to be submitted for review if it contains any of these.

[facebook app review guideline](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/)

1. Facebook Login and also asks for friends, photos, tagged places,
   videos, events, managed groups, posts, or mobile phone
2. Pages API (You need to request manage_pages permissions to enable
   most Marketing API scenarios)
3. Events API
4. Messenger Platform API
5. Instagram Graph API
6. Groups API
7. Business Manager API

So, For my case Do I need to submit the app for review? And If so, what would be the procedure for submitting, I mean what items do I need to choose from [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjI3V.png) to include in submission?

Thanks.

Comment: No, that should not need review.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe. That saves lot of troubles :).

Comment: I'm in almost same situation. So this is great! But is there any document about this??

Comment: Thanks @CBroe. You saved my day